# disabled button and enabled button when progress bar finish?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

how can I make the button disabled while the progress bar is working And when the progress bar is finished, the button is enabled.

my code not work the button is not disabled in the begining.
Thank you.

```
<div id="progressTimer"></div>

<script>
    function () {
        $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    };
</script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Easy-jQuery-Progress-Bar-Timer-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-progressTimer/js/jquery.progressTimer.js'></script>
<script>



            $("#progressTimer").progressTimer({
                timeLimit: 30,
                warningThreshold: 10,
                baseStyle: 'progress-bar-warning',
                warningStyle: 'progress-bar-danger',
                completeStyle: 'progress-bar-info',
                onFinish: function () {
                    $("#btnSave").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            });



</script>


<input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
<div id="progressTimer">
</div>
```

I expect 
the button disabled until the progress bar ends.
button enabled when the progress bar is finished

Comment: $("#btnSave").prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Why not just write the button as disabled in the first place (`<input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" disabled="disabled" />`), instead of trying to disable it with js?   Then when the progress bar is finished, you can remove the disabled property.

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable the button use:

```
$('#btnSave').prop('disabled', false);
$('#btnSave').prop('disabled', true);`
```